# How to get horizontal layout to definition lists with cards with Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have been building a web application using Bootstrap 3. Within that, I used panels to group user elements - displaying data, simple edit forms etc.

I would use a `dl` with the label as a `dt` and the value as the `dd`.
Similarly, I would use forms with the labels inline with the fields

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>Name</dt>
    <dd>Value</dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

I could use `dl-horizontal` just fine within the panel.

Now, however, with Bootstrap 4 panels have become cards, and the `dl-horizontal` class does not seem to have an effect.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-text">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
      <dt>Name</dt>
      <dd>Value</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**
Removed references to forms. I had initially had issues with `form-horizontal` as well, Bootstrap4 does horizontal forms differently

Comment: Some code would be nice....I'd think you would know that with your rep.

Comment: You can see the migration notes for Bootstrap 3 to 4 about the `dl-horizontal` [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#typography). _".dl-horizontal has been dropped. Instead, use .row on <dl> and use grid column classes (or mixins) on its <dt> and <dd> children."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get fully responsive behavior, use:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-text">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-3 text-md-right">Name</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-9">Value</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because in Bootstrap 3 the `dl-horizontal` class only applied to sm+ screens, and it aligned the `<dt>` to the right.

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap 4 no longer supports `dl-horizontal`. The recommended alternative is to use `.row` and `.col*`.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-text">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-4">Name</dt>
      <dd class="col-8">Value</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of list-inline and list-inline-item:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-text">
    <dl class="list-inline">
      <dt class="list-inline-item">Name</dt>
      <dd class="list-inline-item">Value</dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```